# Asp.net mvc 4: $.Get() method call doesn't hit the action inside the controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Here's my jquery code:

```
var url = "@Url.Action("Admin", "EditMovie")" + "/" + id;

$.get(url, function (data) {
  alert("Data Loaded: ");
});
```

And this is my method inside the controller

```
public ActionResult EditMovie(int id)
{            
    return PartialView("BasicMovieInfo", repository.GetMovieByID(id));
}
```

I placed a break point inside the EditMovie action, but it is not being hit. Is there any reason for that?

Comment: Try with `Url.Action("EditMovie", "Admin")` the signature is `public string Action(
 string actionName,
 string controllerName
)`

Comment: @nemesv, you've earned the right to call me idiot. How couldn't I think about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have got the parameters in reverse. See [`UrlHelper.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492758%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). First parameter is the *action name* and the second is the *controller name*. Assuming your controller is named `AdminController`, it should be :

```
var url = "@Url.Action("EditMovie", "Admin")" + "/" + id;
```

Comment: by the way, how do I remove the string concatenation? When I use new {} to include the parameter, I'm getting the error that id is not defined the current context.

Comment: @Richard77 Since you get your `id` in javascript while the page is running on the client side, you can't supply the `id` parameter.